# How do I do a new array of objects from user input in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a to-do list project. I starting building this project with an array of objects like in the code below but now I want to build that array of objects from the scratch using the user input.

I want to load first of all that array of objects because the whole project depends on that array of objects to work.

```
const arrOfObjs = [
 {
  description: 'Wash the dishes',
  completed: false,
  index: 0,
 },

 {
   description: 'Complete To Do list project',
   completed: false,
   index: 1,
 },

 {
   description: 'Understand data structure',
   completed: false,
   index: 2,
 },
];
```

This works well when I refresh the page it loads the array but when I refresh the page for the second time and add a new item to the list it just builds a new item and removes the last ones.

```
const userInput = document.getElementById('add-to-list');
const enter = document.getElementById('returnBtn');

let arrOfObjs = [];

enter.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let userObj = new Task(userInput.value, false, 0);

  arrOfObjs.push(userObj);

  savingOnLocal(arrOfObjs)
});
```

In the savingOnLocal function, I have a localStorage with the key 'tasks' I calling that function from another module.

If I place the function savingOnLocal() outside the curly braces nothing happens. Another thing is that the object I create with the name of user obj should increment the index every time the user creates a new task. Hope you can help me Cheers!!

I'm starting from here:

[image]

This happens if I add 2 new items and after refresh the page:

[image]

But this other happens if I try to add a new item and after refresh the page again, it just gives me the new item and overwrites the others.

[image]

Comment: You need to save the array somewhere so you can retrieve it after a page refresh. A common solution is to use **local storage** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: everytime you refresh the page it starts the complete code from the top so it wil again generate the new array containing 3 items. it won't store your input data after you refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be doing is trying to save the content of your list into the local storage of the navigator. But when you initialize the list, you don't get the value from said local storage. The folowing happens :

1. You load the page and initalize the array.
2. You put some tasks in the array
3. You save theses tasks to local storage
4. The page reloads and the array isn't initialized with the value in the local storage, it's an empty array instead.

What you can do is the folowing :

```
const arrOfObjs = localStorage.getItem('arrayOfObjs');

if (arrOfObjs !== null) { // We are in the case when nothing has been saved yet
    arrOfObjs = [];
}

enter.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let userObj = new Task(userInput.value, false, 0);

  arrOfObjs.push(userObj);

  savingOnLocal(arrOfObjs)
});
```